# I should compare students by month

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
public function getComparisonStudentsByMonth()
{   
    $last_month = date('m', strtotime('-2 month'));
    $previus_month = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));

    return
    $this->db->select('MONTH('student_add_date')', date('m'));
    $this->db->where('student_add_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAYS)');
    $query = $this->db->get('students')->result();
}
```

### Problem

User every month inserting new students and admin page should show the comparison in percentage between months. I should take last month like 100% and compare with current month. I understand the logic but how to do with MySql.

Comment: provide 2-3 examples in your answer and your database structure

Comment: `return` will stop query immediately. after that it wont execute other lines

Answer (score 0):

To get all percentage of every month you can use this:

```
SELECT (MONTH(student_add_date)) AS month_temp, ((count(*) /(SELECT count(*) FROM students)) * 100)percentage from students group by month_temp
```

to get between two month you need to specify month in query. for example i will search in september(9) and oktober(10)

```
SELECT 
(MONTH(student_add_date)) AS month_temp, 
((count(*) /(SELECT count(*) FROM students WHERE MONTH(student_add_date) = 9 OR MONTH(student_add_date) = 10)) * 100)percentace 
from students 
WHERE 
MONTH(student_add_date) = 9 
OR 
MONTH(student_add_date) = 10 
group by month_temp
```

In codeigniter you can run custom query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT 
    (MONTH(student_add_date)) AS month_temp, 
    ((count(*) /(SELECT count(*) FROM students WHERE MONTH(student_add_date) = 9 OR MONTH(student_add_date) = 10)) * 100)percentace 
    from students 
    WHERE 
    MONTH(student_add_date) = 9 
    OR 
    MONTH(student_add_date) = 10 
    group by month_temp');


$result = $query->result_array();

// var_dump($result);

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getComparisonStudentsByMonth()
{   
    $last_month = date('m', strtotime('-2 month'));
    $previus_month = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));

    $last_month = $this->db->where('MONTH(student_add_date)', $last_month)
                                                 ->count_all_results('students');           

    $previus_month = $this->db->where('MONTH(student_add_date)', $previus_month)
                                                 ->count_all_results('students');

    $result = $previus_month * 100 / $last_month;

    return $result;
}
```